# In terms of security, what's the different between using eval() inside js code than to type js code in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, eval

Let's say i take some user input and eval it like this:

```
var a = $('input[type="text"]').val();
eval(a);
```

is it more dangerous than the user himself opens a chrome console and typing:

```
var a = 'SOMETHING BAD';
eval(a);
```

Consider both code pieces runs in the global scope.

Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that a 3rd party could try to leverage the first.

Comment: If you are saving *that* user input, and `eval`ing it when opened by *other* users (like a comment or a posting) - then it is definitely a big problem. If one user's input is rendered to a page seen by no one but just him, then it doesn't make any difference. In your particular case, if you *only* `eval` it back to the user who typed it in, there is no difference from doing it via the console.

Comment: thanks techfoobar your explanation is very helpful for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In and of itself, it's just the same. However, in practice it's much more dangerous to have `eval` code running on your site because it's possible that **somebody else** could manipulate it in such a way that someone ends up running malicious code **accidentally**.

If someone runs something broken through the console, they know what they're doing and if something goes wrong, then they have a pretty good idea what probably caused it. If something just transparently goes wrong without them doing anything obvious, that's worse for the user.